# Go Gae NewContext

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I'm using Go on GAE. One of my tasks is sending an email. I am using [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/mail/#Go_Sending_mail_in_Go) documentation successfully to test.

However, what if I do not want a request handler:

```
func confirm(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        c := appengine.NewContext(r)
                    ...
```

But rather, send the email through a local func:

```
func confirm() {
...
```

Is there any way in Go to do this with GAE? I *think* what Im looking for is a way to call:

```
c := appengine.NewContext(r)
```

But without a request handler, or bypass it in any way possible (which Im reading is probably not possible)

I am thinking a work around could be making an [http request](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/) from my application to my application - but wow is that ugly!

```
resp, err := http.Get("http://localhost:8080/sendMail?to=...")
```

NOTE: After attempting this -- ugly work around I get:
http.DefaultTransport and http.DefaultClient are not available in App Engine. See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/urlfetch/

So this workaround is in fact NOT a work around in that `urlfetch` which is how GAE uses http.GET once again... requires `c := appengine.NewContext(r)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an appengine.Context to interact with external services, including email and urlfetch. You will have to pass the Context instance into your `confirm` function.

Comment: I was afraid that was the answer. Is there any way to pass it something other than *http.Request? Or a fake *http.Request of some type? Im trying to NOT use a request handler if at all possible. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure what your goal is, but app engine won't run any code at all without a request starting your instance first, so even if you could do this, there would be no way to have the code execute. What exactly is the requirement you're trying to solve?

Comment: Ohhhhhhhh +1. i didnt know that, but it answers my question! Thanks so much for following back up